# Taskbar pinning of apps are not being seen And Grub theme installing Problem

Tags: unity, grub2, themes

After I customized my taskbar by using dock preferences, when opening any tasks, they disappear when minimised, but are not getting pinned to taskbar. I want any app that I open & that is running (even if minimised) to appear on the dock bar.

How can I solve that problem ?

Example: Google is open but no icon on dock:

[image]

When I press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> it is showing the app running in the background (but it's not showing on the dock)

Comment: K Sure.But How to solve that problem

Comment: I am not getting app icon also on the dockbar but that desired app is running in background when  super+tab it is showing the app but how to resolve that problem.I want any app that I open should pin to taskbar how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

To keep your apps to **dock**, at first open your app, and when it's icon appear on **dock** just **right click** on icon and select **keep in dock**

To copy themes to folder open your terminal (**ctrl+alt+t**) and enter following
`gksudo nautilus`

this will open the **file manager** with superuser but in safe way.

now you can copy from desired folder and paste to the folder you want.

OR go to this [link](http://www.newlinuxuser.net/the-awn-dock.html) It have explained 3 different ways.

Comment: I am not getting app icon also on the dockbar but that desired app is running in background when we click superkey+tab button it is showing the app but not pinning to dock!!

Comment: @sainikhil which **dock** are you using ?

Comment: Awn setting dock

Comment: @sainikhil I have just added a link at the end of my answer go and check it.

Comment: @akhileshkumar...thanks for helping me..It's working!!!

Comment: @sainikhil You should consider to upvote this answer OR if you want mark it as answer by clicking gray **check sign**